# Masonry elements collapsing onto each other

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins, jquery-masonry, masonry

This is the first time I have used the jQuery plugin [enter link description here](http://masonry.desandro.com/) and I can't work out why it's not displaying correctly; I mean I assume it has something to do with absolute positioning since they are all collapsing into one another, but I believe I have set it up correctly?

**CodePen:** http://codepen.io/gutterboy/pen/bENEyq

**Edit:**

I now have this, http://codepen.io/gutterboy/pen/xZbVBw - I can't seem t get it working with 3 columns with spacing between them though.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="grid">
            <div class="item">
              <div class="image">
                <img src="http://weknowyourdreams.com/images/car/car-03.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
              </div>
              <div class="text">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc de hominis summo bono quaeritur; Pugnant Stoici cum Peripateticis. Quid vero? Ego vero isti, inquam, permitto. Magna laus.
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Item Ends -->
            <div class="item">
              <div class="text">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc de hominis summo bono quaeritur; Pugnant Stoici cum Peripateticis. Quid vero? Ego vero isti, inquam, permitto. Magna laus.
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Item Ends -->
            <div class="item">
              <div class="image">
                <img src="http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/150918170501-frankfurt-motor-show-concept-cars-4-super-169.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
              </div>
              <div class="text">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc de hominis summo bono quaeritur; Pugnant Stoici cum Peripateticis. Quid vero? Ego vero isti, inquam, permitto. Magna laus.
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Item Ends -->
            <div class="item">
              <div class="image">
                <img src="http://resources.carsguide.com.au/styles/cg_hero_large/s3/McLaren-P1_0.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
              </div>
              <div class="text">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc de hominis summo bono quaeritur; Pugnant Stoici cum Peripateticis. Quid vero? Ego vero isti, inquam, permitto. Magna laus.
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Item Ends -->
            <div class="item">
              <div class="image">
                <img src="http://car-pictures.cars.com/images/?IMG=cac10foc051c01401.png&WIDTH=624&AUTOTRIM=1&SPECIAL=&ACT=F" class="img-responsive" />
              </div>
              <div class="text">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc de hominis summo bono quaeritur; Pugnant Stoici cum Peripateticis. Quid vero? Ego vero isti, inquam, permitto. Magna laus.
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc de hominis summo bono quaeritur; Pugnant Stoici cum Peripateticis. Quid vero? Ego vero isti, inquam, permitto. Magna laus.
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc de hominis summo bono quaeritur; Pugnant Stoici cum Peripateticis. Quid vero? Ego vero isti, inquam, permitto. Magna laus.            
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Item Ends -->
            <div class="item">
              <div class="image">
                <img src="http://weknowyourdreams.com/images/car/car-03.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
              </div>
              <div class="text">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc de hominis summo bono quaeritur; Pugnant Stoici cum Peripateticis. Quid vero? Ego vero isti, inquam, permitto. Magna laus.
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Item Ends -->
            <div class="item">
              <div class="image">
                <img src="http://media.truelocal.com.au/1/B/11A5BD61-BB2D-4E6D-BF87-FB2C5B4C56CB/budget-car-and-truck-rental-brisbane-brisbane-car-rental-rental-cars-brisbane-5427-938x704.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
              </div>
              <div class="text">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc de hominis summo bono quaeritur; Pugnant Stoici cum Peripateticis. Quid vero? Ego vero isti, inquam, permitto. Magna laus.
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Item Ends -->
            <div class="item">
              <div class="image">
                <img src="http://weknowyourdreams.com/images/car/car-03.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
              </div>
              <div class="text">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc de hominis summo bono quaeritur; Pugnant Stoici cum Peripateticis. Quid vero? Ego vero isti, inquam, permitto. Magna laus.
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Item Ends -->
            <div class="item">
              <div class="image">
                <img src="http://weknowyourdreams.com/images/car/car-03.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
              </div>
              <div class="text">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc de hominis summo bono quaeritur; Pugnant Stoici cum Peripateticis. Quid vero? Ego vero isti, inquam, permitto. Magna laus.
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Item Ends -->
            <div class="item">
              <div class="image">
                <img src="http://weknowyourdreams.com/images/car/car-03.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
              </div>
              <div class="text">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc de hominis summo bono quaeritur; Pugnant Stoici cum Peripateticis. Quid vero? Ego vero isti, inquam, permitto. Magna laus.
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Item Ends -->
            <div class="item">
              <div class="image">
                <img src="http://weknowyourdreams.com/images/car/car-03.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
              </div>
              <div class="text">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc de hominis summo bono quaeritur; Pugnant Stoici cum Peripateticis. Quid vero? Ego vero isti, inquam, permitto. Magna laus.
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Item Ends -->        
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**SCSS:**

```
.item {

  width: 33.33333%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;

  .image {

  }

  .text {
    padding: 15px;
  }

}

.grid-sizer {
  width: 33.33333%;
}
```

**JS:**

```
var $grid = $('.grid').masonry({
    itemSelector: '.item',
    columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
    columnWidth: '33.33333%',
    percentPosition: true,
    gutter: 10
  });

// layout Masonry after each image loads
grid.imagesLoaded().progress( function() {
    $grid.masonry('layout');
});
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @NenadVracar Not bad, but I need spacing between them.

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vLEKYJ

Comment: Thanks but if you add borders around them you will notice there is no spacing as I need margin spacing. However I came up with a fix after playing around with your version :)

Answer (score 0):

if run it with the standard js it works

```
$(document).ready( function() {

  $('.grid').masonry({
    itemSelector: '.item',
    columnWidth: 160
  });

});
```

[http://masonry.desandro.com/layout.html](http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/osFxj)

Comment: I need percentages though, not fixed widths.

Comment: according to the manual it should be possible; http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/JFpeg

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, typing in the wrong item. I had to be somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

After checking out the solution posted by *Nenad Vracar* in the comments I started playing around with it more - he fixed the collapsing issue, but I need margin spacing between them whilst keeping 3 columns.

The fix, add/change the below to the existing css class:

```
.item {
    width: calc(33.33333333% - 10px);
    margin-right: 10px;

    &:nth-child(3n) {
        margin-right: 0;
    }

}
```

**New JS:**

```
var $grid = $('.grid').masonry({
  itemSelector: '.item',
  percentPosition: true
});

// layout Masonry after each image loads
$grid.imagesLoaded().progress( function() {
  $grid.masonry('layout');
});
```

Only problem is the 3 columns don't make up *exactly* the whole width, they are a few pixels short.